# How can I check keyboard key state within a mousemove event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events

I want to be able to use the space key to modify the behavior of the mouse while it is held down.   Without knowing better I am imagining it involves some kind of coordination between two (or three) event handler - `mousemove`, `keydown`, and `keyup`.   But I am wondering if there is some way to handle it entirely within one event handler - `mousemove`.

Example code to give an idea of what I hope to be able to do...

```
        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (Keyboard.KeyDown == Keys.Space)
                {
                    /* Do modified behavour for left mouse being held down while 
                    space is also held down */
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do normal behavour for left mouse being held down
                }

            }
        }
```

Is something like this possible or will I have to save the state of the space key to a class variable using keydown event handler and check it with the mouse move handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set a variable in your KeyDown-Event and check it in your MouseEvent:

```
bool buttonpressed = false;
private void KeyDown_Event(object s, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.KeyCode == KeyCode.Space)
      buttonpressed = true;
   else
      buttonpressed = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (buttonPressed)
                {
                    /* Do modified behavour for left mouse being held down while 
                    space is also held down */
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do normal behavour for left mouse being held down
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks.   I knew I could do it this way but thought it might be slightly buggy to handle a combined physical action with three separate event handlers, but having implemented it now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

IT could be done using Control.ModifierKeys & Control.MouseButtons. But only works for kays like shift, ctrl and alt.

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
        {
            if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
            { // here you go

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a variable that tracks when `Keys.Space` is in the `Pressed` state, then trigger it with `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      // Check if Key.Space pressed
      if(SpacePressed) {
           // Do something
      }
 }

 private void KeyPressed_Event(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
      // Check if Key.Space pressed
      if(e.Key == Key.Space) {
           SpacePressed = true;
      }
 }

 private void KeyRelease_Event(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
      // Check if Key.Space pressed
      if(e.Key == Key.Space) {
           SpacePressed = false;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use PInvoke to call [GetKeyState](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetKeyState.html) in User32.dll.